# devise invitable same invitation token for same email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

In devise invitable, each time we invite a user with same email address we generate a different invitation token. Is it able to always generate a same token for the same email address? I looked into their code and find:

```
raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :invitation_token)
```

shall I overwrite this token generator to take email as key to generate a token?

Thanks.